# Rollback not happening for ForEach container in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have the following use case:

I am trying to move the files in one folder to another folder. If any file is corrupt then whole process should be rolled back and no files should be moved.

For achieving this I am making use of one data flow task and one file system task. Data flow task would check for the integrity of the file and file system task would then move the file. These two tasks are in foreach container. 
The transaction property of foreach is set to required and for the two tasks inside it, i am keeping it as supported.

Issue: There are 6 files in one folder which are to be moved. The file # 4 is corrupt. I want the whole task to rollback when system detects the corrupt file. However, this is not happening and files uptil file no 3 get moved.

Screen shot attached.[image]

Comment: According to this: http://www.bidn.com/blogs/devinknight/ssis/501/using-database-transactions-across-multiple-ssis-tasks a file system task will not roll back it's operation, so you'll need to manually allow for this by doing something like moving files in to a holding folder and only on success of the entire task, move them all to the correct spot

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Ohh, i wasn't aware of this. Anyway thank you for your help. Is that documented somewhere on Microsoft SSIS website?

Comment: I can't find it but it looks like it's addressed in an identical post here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/459dcd05-38c2-4223-be80-dd979818fc73/rollback-not-happening-for-foreach-container-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices Transactions would imply for example that if you delete or move 500 10Gb files, they can be rolled back. I just isn't going to be supported. Here's more info: http://visakhm.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/implementing-transaction-over-file.html

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Yes, i posted that hoping that someone would address it. Visakh provided a solution.. Thank you.